# Jade.js with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js

I currently have the following code

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Test
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css')
    script(src="/javascripts/jquery.js")

  body
    script.
      var start = Date.now()
      console.log(start)          
      div(id='microtime')
        p
    script.
      $(document).ready(function() {
      var end = (Date.now() - start) / 1000
      console.log(end)
      $('#microtime p').text = 'aa'
      })
```

Im trying to make a microtime to show page load time, currently the code shows 0 errors on console but the #microtime p text its not beeing updated, the div microtime doesnt have any css attributtes and console.log is working fine...

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
$('#microtime p').text = 'aa'
```

with

```
$('#microtime p').text('aa');
```